# What is the `[...]` in the sqlalchemy documentation?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

The Sqlalchemy documentation uses the `[...]` syntax in its examples. What does this symbol mean? Does the `()` also have some special meaning in this case?
Example:

```
SELECT users.id AS users_id,
        users.name AS users_name,
        users.fullname AS users_fullname,
        users.nickname AS users_nickname
FROM users ORDER BY users.id
[...] ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[...]` in this case means "details omitted for clarity". For example, the tutorial example [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#getting-a-connection) would actually produce output like

```
2022-08-15 12:00:20,656 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-08-15 12:00:20,658 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select 'hello world'
2022-08-15 12:00:20,658 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00061s] ()
[('hello world',)]
2022-08-15 12:00:20,659 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

but the `[generated in 0.00061s]` clutters things up so the tutorial omits it

```
BEGIN (implicit)
select 'hello world'
[...] ()
[('hello world',)]
ROLLBACK
```

As for the `()`, they show that no parameters were passed. If the query had been parameterized, e.g.,

```py
result = conn.execute(sa.text("select :hello"), dict(hello='Howdy!'))
```

then the tutorial would have displayed

```
select ?
[...] ('Howdy!',)
```